# Is it possible to filter Pull Requests by team alias, tag, etc

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

My team frequently has PRs out for a bigger project that is very active and has numerous PRs out at any given time. We're trying to filter these PRs so that only PRs relevant to our team are shown.

Is there any way to do this? The filters in the UI allow to search by creator, reviewer and the target branch, but none of these are useful to us (because "Assigned To" has to be an individual and cannot be a group alias). There are 'tags' that can be assigned to the PRs, but these cannot be filtered by.

Answer (score 2):

The filters you see are what there are, but there are a few extensions that give more capabilities, for example - [Pull Request Manager Hub](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=caribeiro84.pull-request-manager-hub):

[image]

You have more filters there (but no by team/tag) and a free search.

You can find more extensions regarding this [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=pull%20request&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Repos&sortBy=Relevance).